# Add Columns in Rows with a Negative Sign

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the text file:

```
description, date, amount
Car,02/06/2021,26
Desk,06/21/2020,-6
Hockey Stick,07/20/2021,-26
```

I essentially want to take the amount and add the numbers together even if it is a negative (with the "-" sign). I don't know how to do this, I think python is not recognising the negative numbers as `int`s:

```
data = open("transactions.txt", "r")
info = data.readlines()
data.close()
budget = 0
for line in info:
    splitting = line.split(",")
    budget += float(splitting[2]) <-- Error
    print(budget)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip the first line, as it's a full-text header. So it's not the `-6`, but the `amount`.
Something like

```
for line in info[1:]:
```

should do the job.